# Update local sqlite database from Adobe AIR application

Tags: sqlite, air, adobe

I have a local sqlite database which is created by an IE addon. The sqlite database cannot be updated from a Adobe AIR application which I use as a frontend. The exception is as follows

SQLError:'Error #3132:Datatype type mismatch.',details:'could not convert floating point value to integer without loss of data.',operation:'execute',detailID:'2302'

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are trying to save a Number type (in air (as3) it is floating point type) to an Integer in Sqlite, you need to change column type in sqlite to be float, or in air if you need an integer change type to an int.